# Another word for breakfast

Tags: single-word-requests

My English vocab is not so good(as it is a second language to me). What i wanted to know was, is there another word for breakfast. Specially if its something that is being eaten right after waking up. Is it still  called breakfast or is there another word for it?

Comment: It's still breakfast, unless you wake up around lunchtime.

Comment: There is [**early morning tea**](http://www.oncecalledhome.com/2010/05/earlymorningtea/). *"Early morning tea was served on a tray and started the day sharply at six as we gathered around Mom’s bed."* And [here](http://www.edwardianpromenade.com/food/a-proper-early-morning-tea/) is *"Early morning tea, brought by a housemaid who lit the bedroom fire while the lady sipped her tea, was accompanied by paper-thin bread and butter, or plain biscuits."* Among some couples, there is a ritual where one of them fetches tea and biscuits to eat in bed. Breakfast will follow a bit later.

Comment: @Lawrence You should post that as the answer.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Done. :)

Comment: There are terms like "morning meal", but none (that I can think of) that are as specific yet well-understood as "breakfast".

Comment: Morning tea does not have to be tea. Lots of people in many places drink morning coffee in bed. But of course neither is breakfast. Breakfast is breakfast.

Comment: Single word requests need the sentence in which the word will be used!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is funny cause the word you actually need is a loan from the Latin word  *ientaculum* (breakfast, particularly right upon getting up).

The word you can use in English is  ***jentacular*** (of or pertaining to a breakfast taken early in the morning, or immediately upon getting up) which has been derived from ientaculum. Though this may not be exactly what you require: jentacular is an adjective.
Example:

- Would you care to have a jentacular coffee with me?
- I took a post-jentacular walk to settle my stomach.
- I like a jentacular run in the morning.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jentacular
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ientaculum#Latin

Comment: That's an interesting word that I would bet very few English speakers have ever heard.

Comment: Even so, it doesn't answer the question. It would be a modifier to"breakfast" rather than another word for it as the OP is looking for. "Jentacular breakfast"

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson “jentacular” in James Stormonth, Etymological and Pronouncing Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition, William Blackwood and Sons (1879), page 755: “jentacular, a. jĕn-tăk-ūl-ėr (L. jentaculum, a breakfast taken immediately on getting up), applied to a breakfast taken early in the morning, or immediately on getting up: pre-jentacular, applied to what is done early in the morning, as taking a breakfast before getting up.”(https://books.google.co.in/books?id=J2kCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA755&dq=jentacular&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q=jentacular&f=false)

Comment: @JustTolerateMe Right, that seems to re-iterate your original post. Adjective.

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree, I was not one of the few.

Answer (score 4):

It's still breakfast, unless you wake up around lunchtime.

> **breakfast** *noun*
> A meal eaten in the morning, the first of the day.
> [- lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/breakfast)

Comment: I regularly refer to my first meal of the day, regardless of the time I wake up, as "breakfast." After all, it is the thing that "breaks my fast" from not having eaten since the day prior.

Answer (score 0):

There is **early morning tea** which is a snack before breakfast, just after waking, taken in the bedroom, or even in bed. Among some couples this is a ritual when one of them fetches tea and biscuits to eat in bed. This isn't "breakfast in bed": breakfast will follow a bit later.

Some references to this 'meal':

[**Early Morning Tea**](http://www.oncecalledhome.com/2010/05/earlymorningtea/)

> Early morning tea was served on a tray and started the day sharply at six as we gathered around Mom’s bed.

[**A Proper Early Morning Tea**](http://www.edwardianpromenade.com/food/a-proper-early-morning-tea/)

> Early morning tea, brought by a housemaid who lit the bedroom fire while the lady sipped her tea, was accompanied by paper-thin bread and butter, or plain biscuits: these were home-made, or probably Digestives at ninepence a pound, Osborne at sevenpence, or Thin Arrowroot at eightpence. The ritual of early morning tea was strictly observed in even moderately wealthy houses.
> <sub>Kate Caffrey’s *The 1900s Lady*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If one eats only once between waking up and the beginning of lunchtime (approximately 11:30), one will call that meal *breakfast*, regardless of how light or substantial it is, and regardless of when within that period it is consumed. There is, incidentally, no usable synonym for *breakfast*.

If one eats more than once during that period, then the most substantial meal consumed within it will be called *breakfast*. If one eats something light before it, immediately upon waking up, that would be the *early morning tea*, eloquently described in one of the quotations provided by Weather Wane. If one eats something light after the breakfast, but before the lunchtime, that would be referred to as *elevenses* or *morning tea* (or *mid-morning tea*, if it is important to avoid any possibility of confusion with the early one). All these terms, other than *breakfast*, are confined to British English (with *elevenses* rarely used anywhere outside the U.K. itself), and have no equivalents in American English. It should be noted that, if one does have an early morning tea, then one's breakfast will not be the very first thing one eats in a day, notwithstanding the etymology.

One consequence of the above is that the label that will be used for a particular meal/snack partially depends on what else one intends to eat during the morning. The very same thing that would be referred to as an early morning tea, if one plans to have a 'proper' breakfast later, would itself be referred to as a breakfast, albeit a very light one, if one does not intend to eat anything else until lunchtime.

There is an exception to the above if one does not intend to have a lunch: in such a case the meal that would otherwise be called *breakfast* may be called *brunch*, particularly if consumed later in the morning and if it is substantial enough to be a reasonable substitute for both meals. One may, however, still call such a meal *breakfast*, particularly if one wishes to avoid the associations with an atmosphere of indulgence and leisure, which the term *brunch* may carry.

One would not normally use the term *breakfast* for something that is consumed after 11:30 A.M. or so. On the rare occasions on which somebody does use the word for a meal consumed at a later time, the word would be understood to be used in scare quotes, and some explanation would be expected of why one uses it in such a nonstandard way (e.g. that one works at night, and so has to organise one's life differently from most other people, or that the meal consists of the dishes that are customarily eaten for breakfast).

Comment: I've never heard of "early morning tea" except as a description rather than the name of a meal, that is it is more like "a midday meal" than "lunch". To confuse things further there are a lot of (mainly corporate) eating establishments who offer "All Day Breakfast" from the time they open in the morning right up to when the stop serving at night. In this case a "breakfast" is "a full English (or Scottish, or Irish, or Welsh) breakfast and describes the style of the meal instead of the time when it's served.

Comment: @BoldBen, indeed, one doesn't hear the phrase *early morning tea* very often, but that's probably because what it stands for is somewhat quaint—it may be noteworthy that both quotations in Weather Wane's answer are about a bygone era. However, if you were in the habit of having something like that upon waking up, and before breakfast, what would you call it, other than 'early morning tea'? In any event, what is crucial for responding to the OP is that such a thing would not be called 'breakfast' if one expects to sit down for a real breakfast later, after getting dressed for the day.

Comment: I'm not sure about your assertion that the *most substantial* morning meal would necessarily be called breakfast. It seems more appropriate for the *first* substantial meal. Example: Maybe I eat a lot but when on a full day bike ride, "second breakfast" (too early for "elevenses", and not "brunch" as a lunch is planned) may be bigger than (first) breakfast.

Answer (score -1):

‘Breakfast’ refers to ‘breaking’ your ‘fast’.  You have not eaten for up to 12 hours, which is why the term ‘fast’ applies; and so in taking the first breakfast of you day, you are ‘breaking’ your ‘fast’.

But one kind of breakfast that people love is the one they have immediately after waking:  it is called, simply, ‘breakfast in bed’.  It’s not a single word, but nor is, for example, the French ‘petit déjeuner’.  But it is still in common use, along with that third breakfast that we like to take after 10:30 on a week end:  brunch.  Breakfast in bed was once for wealthy aristocrats like Bertie Wooster, served by his Butler, Jeeves or men served by their wives.  Now, I hope, the service is gender neutral.  But it is deliciously decadent.